# How do I write a test class invoked from a flow?

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I'm really struggling with writing my first test class for an Invocable method. It's an apex class that's fired from a flow. I've read a bunch of posts and examples but I haven't seen anything that seems to direct relate to my code. Here's the class:

```
public class UpdateArchivedTasks 
{
    
    public class FlowInputs
    {
        @InvocableVariable public String a_DeleteAccountId;
        @InvocableVariable public String a_MasterAccountId;
        @InvocableVariable public String a_DeletePrimaryContactId;
        @InvocableVariable public String a_MasterPrimaryContactId;
    }
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Update Archived Task')  
    public static void updateArchived(List<FlowInputs> request) 
    {
        
        String ThisDeleteAccountId          = request[0].a_DeleteAccountId;
        String ThisMasterAccountId          = request[0].a_MasterAccountId;
        String ThisDeletePrimaryContactId   = request[0].a_DeletePrimaryContactId;
        String ThisMasterPrimaryContactId   = request[0].a_MasterPrimaryContactId;
        
        Task[] records = [SELECT Id, Subject, WhoId, WhatId from Task where AccountId = :ThisDeleteAccountId ALL ROWS];
        for (Task record: records)
        {
            // change the subject as a show it worked.
            //record.Subject = 'a' + record.Subject;
            
            // if WhoId is a_DeletePrimaryContactId, set it to a_MasterPrimaryContactId
            if(record.WhoId == ThisDeletePrimaryContactId){
                record.WhoId = ThisMasterPrimaryContactId;
            } 
            // If WhatId is a_DeleteAccountId, set it to a_MasterAccountId
            if(record.WhatId == ThisDeleteAccountId){
                record.WhatId = ThisMasterAccountId;
            } 
        }
        update records;
    }
}
```

I don't know where to start with the test class. I'm passing in four strings from a flow via an apex action. So I don't really understand how I test this. I know the code itself is reliable enough, I just don't really understand yet the Apex Text Class creation process as much as I'd like. I've only delved into Apex because of a limitation updating archived records in Visual Flow.

```
@isTest
private class UpdateArchivedTasksTestClass {

    private static testMethod void validateUpdateArchivedTasks() {
        
        //@InvocableVariable public String a_DeleteAccountId;
        //@InvocableVariable public String a_MasterAccountId;
        //@InvocableVariable public String a_DeletePrimaryContactId;
        //@InvocableVariable public String a_MasterPrimaryContactId;        
    
        Test.startTest();
        
                    


        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Update: This is the code that ended up passing:

```
@isTest
private class UpdateArchivedTasksTestClass {
    // Recommended practice is to use a @testSetup annotated method to create
    // the common data required for each test.
    // It can help test execution speed.
    @testSetup
    static void makeData(){
        // Since you're working with Accounts, Contacts, and Tasks here, you should
        // create all of that data explicitly
        Account testAcc1 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account 1');
        Account testAcc2 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account 2');
        insert new List<Account>{testAcc1, testAcc2};

        // For most fields, we need to query (or re-query) the record after
        // performing DML to get the updated values.
        // The record Id is one (perhaps the only) exception.
        // After a new record is inserted, the Id is automatically populated
        Contact testContact1 = new Contact(AccountId = testAcc1.Id, LastName = 'McPerson');
        Contact testContact2 = new Contact(AccountId = testAcc2.Id, LastName = 'McLastNameFace');
        insert new List<Contact>{testContact1, testContact2};

        Task testTask1 = new Task(WhatId = testAcc1.Id, WhoId = testContact1.Id);
        insert testTask1;
    }

    // The 'testMethod' keyword has been deprecated for a while
    // The preferred approach is to use the @isTest annotation
    @isTest
    private static void validateUpdateArchivedTasks() {
        // The method you're trying to test here takes its input as instances of
        // UpdateArchivedTasks.FlowInputs (we need to use <outer class name>.<inner class name>
        // except when the code is part of the outer class).
        // Just another thing you need to create yourself.
        UpdateArchivedTasks.FlowInputs firstInput = new UpdateArchivedTasks.FlowInputs();
        
        // The unfortunate thing about using a @testSetup method is that you
        //   do need to perform queries to get at the test data (for each test)
        Map<Id, Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
        Map<Id, Contact> contactsMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id, LastName, AccountId FROM Contact]);

        List<Task> tasksList = [SELECT Id, WhoId, WhatId FROM Task];

        // The slightly tricky part here is figuring out how to get Ids of different
        //   records than what the task already has.
        // This is one approach.
        Map<Id, Account> otherAccountsMap = accountsMap.clone();
        Map<Id, Contact> otherContactsMap = contactsMap.clone();

        // If we remove Ids from the account/contacts map that appear in
        //   any task, then we're left with the records that are not referenced
        //   by any task.
        // The clone() business just above here ensures that accountsMap and contactsMap
        //   will still contain _all_ of the test accounts and contacts (in case
        //   that ends up being helpful later)
        for(Task t :tasksList){
            otherAccountsMap.remove(t.WhatId);
            otherContactsMap.remove(t.WhoId);
        }

        Account otherAccount = otherAccountsMap.values()[0];
        Contact otherContact = otherContactsMap.values()[0];

        // Finally, we can set the data that your flow would be setting
        firstInput.a_DeleteAccountId = tasksList[0].WhatId;
        firstInput.a_MasterAccountId = otherAccount.Id;
        firstInput.a_DeletePrimaryContactId = tasksList[0].WhoId;
        firstInput.a_MasterPrimaryContactId = otherContact.Id;
    
        Test.startTest();
        // To run a static method, we do not need an instance of the class that holds them
        // In fact, static methods _cannot_ be called from an instance of the class
        // It's just <class name>.<static method name>
        // You do still need to provide the appropriate arguments though (like with any other method)
        UpdateArchivedTasks.updateArchived(
            new List<UpdateArchivedTasks.FlowInputs>{firstInput}
        );
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! In the end, there isn't that much difference between testing "normal" code, and something like this. Sure, your class has some special annotations to allow it to be used in a flow, but it's still an Apex class. The normal advice should still apply. 1) Set up test data. 2) Get an instance of the class you want to test. 3) Call the method you want to test. 4) Gather the results, and make assertions to validate the code's behavior.

Comment: Cont'd: If you've started to write a test class, please [edit] your question to include it. Knowing where you are right now, and having a good description of where, precisely, you're stuck helps people make more accurate and tailored answers.

Comment: @DerekF Thank you for your comment. I added what little I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unit tests, we're responsible for setting up (nearly) all aspects of the environment that the test runs in. Some things like data in the `Users` SObject, and custom metadata type records are "Setup objects" and always present, even in tests.

Everything else, we need to create. The same holds true for your flow variables. They need to be set by you (programmatically, via apex) as part of the test setup.

A general example of the type of setup you'd be doing is this:

```java
@isTest
private class UpdateArchivedTasksTestClass {
    // Recommended practice is to use a @testSetup annotated method to create
    //   the common data required for each test.
    // It can help test execution speed.
    @testSetup
    static void makeData(){
        // Since you're working with Accounts, Contacts, and Tasks here, you should
        //   create all of that data explicitly
        Account testAcc1 = new Account(<field name = value pairs here>);
        Account testAcc2 = new Account(<field name = value pairs here>);
        insert new List<Account>{testAcc1, testAcc2};

        // For most fields, we need to query (or re-query) the record after
        //   performing DML to get the updated values.
        // The record Id is one (perhaps the only) exception.
        // After a new record is inserted, the Id is automatically populated
        Contact testContact1 = new Contact(AccountId = testAcc1.Id, LastName = 'McPerson');
        Contact testContact2 = new Contact(AccountId = testAcc2.Id, LastName = 'McLastNameFace');
        insert new List<Contact>{testContact1, testContact2};

        Task testTask1 = new Task(WhatId = testAcc1.Id, WhoId = testContact1.Id);
        insert testTask1;
    }

    // The 'testMethod' keyword has been deprecated for a while
    // The preferred approach is to use the @isTest annotation
    @isTest
    private static void validateUpdateArchivedTasks() {
        // The method you're trying to test here takes its input as instances of
        // UpdateArchivedTasks.FlowInputs (we need to use <outer class name>.<inner class name>
        //   except when the code is part of the outer class).
        // Just another thing you need to create yourself.
        UpdateArchivedTasks.FlowInputs firstInput = new UpdateArchivedTasks.FlowInputs();

        // The unfortunate thing about using a @testSetup method is that you
        //   do need to perform queries to get at the test data (if you need
        //   it to do further setup, that is)
        Map<Id, Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
        Map<Id, Contact> contactsMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id, LastName, AccountId FROM Contact]);

        List<Task> tasksList = [SELECT Id, WhoId, WhatId FROM Contact];

        // The slightly tricky part here is figuring out how to get Ids of different
        //   records than what the task already has.
        // This is one approach.
        Map<Id, Account> otherAccountsMap = accountsMap.clone();
        Map<Id, Contact> otherContactsMap = contactsMap.clone();

        // If we remove Ids from the account/contacts map that appear in
        //   any task, then we're left with the records that are not referenced
        //   by any task.
        // The clone() business just above here ensures that accountsMap and contactsMap
        //   will still contain _all_ of the test accounts and contacts (in case
        //   that ends up being helpful later)
        for(Task t :tasksList){
            otherAccountsMap.remove(t.WhatId);
            otherContactsMap.remove(t.WhoId);
        }

        Account otherAccount = otherAccountsMap.values()[0];
        Contact otherContact = otherContactsMap.values()[0];

        // Finally, we can set the data that your flow would be setting
        firstInput.a_DeleteAccountId = tasksList[0].WhatId;
        firstInput.a_MasterAccountId = otherAccount.Id;
        firstInput.a_DeletePrimaryContactId = tasksList[0].WhoId;
        firstInput.a_MasterPrimaryContactId = otherContact.Id;
    
        Test.startTest();
        // To run a static method, we do not need an instance of the class that holds them
        // In fact, static methods _cannot_ be called using an instance of the class
        // It's just <class name>.<static method name>
        // You do still need to provide the appropriate arguments though (like with any other method)
        UpdateArchivedTasks.updateArchived(
            new List<UpdateArchivedTasks.FlowInputs>{firstInput}
        );
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

You'll need to make adjustments to that, of course, but I hope it helps illustrate what you need to do (and that it's not that different from any of the advice you've already read).

Don't forget to make assertions (whatever changes the code you are testing makes, you should have an assertion for) and also test multiple scenarios (like what happens if the "delete" and "master" variables end up being the same?)

Comment: Thank you so much @Derek F. You are an absolute life saver. And thanks for the commenting. It really helped understand the steps. You're a star. Thank you for you help.

Comment: This Trailhead module on unit testing may be useful, it explains some standard testing patterns: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/unit-testing-on-the-lightning-platform